# how to add noindex in metadata on nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

How to add noindex in metadata on nextjs 13?

Tried to add to "noindex: true" with no success here:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Website title",
  description:
    "My description",
};
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
export const metadata = {
  robots: {
    index: false,
    follow: true,
    nocache: true,
    googleBot: {
      index: true,
      follow: false,
      noimageindex: true,
      'max-video-preview': -1,
      'max-image-preview': 'large',
      'max-snippet': -1,
    },
  },
};
```

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#robots

Comment: This is wrong, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

In Next.js 14, you set it via metadata as follows:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Website title",
  description: "My description",
  robots: {
    index: false,
    follow: false,
  },
};
```